# How to access mnemonics in Intellij 2017+ on Mac?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, mnemonics

There is some evidence in the Intellij codebase they support `ALT`(/Meta)+`CTL` - `(mnemonic)` in Mac.

E.g: in `platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/MnemonicWrapper.java`

```
  if (SystemInfo.isMac && Registry.is("ide.mac.alt.mnemonic.without.ctrl")) {
```

And the corresponding `resource` value in `./platform/util/resources/misc/registry.properties` is set to `true` :

```
ide.mac.alt.mnemonic.without.ctrl=true
```

However pressing those two modifier keys together with .. say .. `F` (for `File` in the main menu) does not work for me on `Sierra` with the latest `2017.1` intellij.

Is this supposed to work? Is there any other way to get mnemonics working on Mac.

Note: please do not comment/respond *"mnemonics are not encouraged/supported on mac"*.  I am ***more*** than well aware of this terrible shortcoming on OS/X. However in previous versions of ***Intellij*** it ***has*** been possible to use mnemonics on Mac: and it would be a big boost to have them working again.

**Update** A `YouTrack` issue was requested by the Intellij Jetbrains support lead. It is here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175624

CTRL-ALT-(Mnemonic) DOES work.

The JetBrains lead Serge Baranov also mentioned that ALT-(Mnenomic) is *supposed* to work.  It did not / does not for any of my laptops on 2017.X.

The Jetbrains support team led by Serge Baranov worked diligently on this - but were unable to reproduce. I expressed surprise since a half dozen installations on my side - all do not work. Apparently for their testing team it *does* work. One of my Mac's was factory new in June 2017 with Sierra and I installed IJ Ultimate 2017.1 without any changes from defaults. It did not work.

It is unclear what conditions were required for the Alt-Mnemonics to work on 2017.X.

*** Another update*** . Jetbrains has provided a fix for this: see last answer.

Comment: Do you have mnemonics enabled in IntelliJ IDEA settings? Does it work with just Alt?

Comment: @CrazyCoder *Is* there such a setting - and if so *where* is it?

Comment: Did you try typing `mnemonic` in the settings search filter [like this](http://i.imgur.com/We2ONHN.png)?

Comment: I did search for `mnemonic` in the keymap but not in the settings.  Please make this an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure mnemonics are not disabled in IntelliJ IDEA settings:

[image: mnemonics]

By default mnemonics should work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> on Mac.

If you prefer only <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>, add `-Dide.mac.alt.mnemonic.without.ctrl=false` in `Help` | `Edit Custom VM Options` (*Processes Alt-based shortcuts for mnemonics in addition to Ctrl+Alt-based shortcuts. Affect MacOS only.*)

There is also a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.x versions which causes mnemonics to work via <kbd>Alt</kbd> in dialogs, but not in the menu. Adding `-Dide.mnemonic.helper.old=true` in `Help` | `Edit Custom VM Options` will workaround this issue. The fix will be available in 2017.2.x.

Comment: This sounds great!  It is not *completely* working yet for me: I did uncheck that option but `ALT` alone still does not work. However `CLT-ALT` *is* working now.  I will try different combination of the `-Dide.mac.alt.mnemonic.without.ctrl=true`

Comment: The `-Dide.mac.alt.mnemonic.without.ctrl` is not working: I tried setting it both true and false in the `idea.vmoptions` .  Have you been able to find a way to get ALT alone to do the trick?

Comment: `ALT` alone is not working ;(  Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you run on [JetBrains Runtime](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879)?

Comment: I am running on the `openjdk version 1.8.0.112 [boot, bundled]`

Comment: Any further thoughts on this?

Comment: Feel free to file a bug at YouTrack.

Comment: Is there any hope of it getting attention within say two years?  Prior bugs I have created or upvoted have taken 3+ years or simply not been fixed.

Comment: There is always hope, a lot of bugs get fixed within day or even hours.

Comment: Ok I will try to get a bug report this weekend.

Comment: Hi Sergey!  I finally was able to create this bug. I have more details on this: it does not work in El Capitan either.  Here is the `YouTrack`: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-175624

Comment: Thanks so much for prioritizing the work from your team on this issue. I'm really sorry the `Alt-(mnemonic)` issue was not able to be resolved even after in depth troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **Serge Baranov** of JetBrains : **we now have a solution**

Add the following to `Custom VM Options`

```
-Dide.mnemonic.helper.old=true
```

In addition a fix will be added to `2017.2`

Comment: The The Jetbrains QA team did a great job of getting the info together and informing Jetbrains development.   Jetbrains development briefly looked at the bug and in February 2018 *passed on trying to fix it*.   Now I do not know what to do about this situation.