# How to use Option in Intellij Keymaps?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

I am trying to add `Option-i | u`  for "Find usages" as shown in this dialog (Note that the "i" is lowercase - `shift` is not depressed):

[image]

But after having selected OK and then going back into `Actions` we see that the setting did not "take":

[image]

Note: I do have custom keymap entries to use  `Option-` for accessing *Main Menu* items.  But why is `Option` not working in this case?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: Option key is normally used for mnemonics. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543906/104891.

Answer (score 2):

On macOS, "Option" is used for typing special characters, thus when editor is focused and you hit Option-I the shortcut you assigned won't work (it will type a character instead).
However, when no editing field is selected, the shortcut should work (e.g. from tool windows).

Comment: @StephenBoesch as for workaround, please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876485/how-to-disable-typing-special-characters-when-pressing-option-key-in-mac-os-x).

Comment: Actually I am already using an alternate input keyboard with blanks created by ukelele